# Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after refresh

Tags: windows-10

I just did a Windows Refresh in Windows 10. Now I cannot even log in. It seems the USB ports are unresponsive. I know they work as I can enter the BIOS on startup, but when Windows starts the num lock light shuts off and the whole keyboard is unresponsive.

I cannot get into Safe Mode and I can’t login to update drivers.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this link](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/9997-windows-10-mouse-keyboard-not-working.html) 
Possible solution from the link:

> I was able to resolve my issue. I started the computer and when Windows started to load, I interrupted power (did not shut off the computer using the start button, but physically unplugged it). If you are working with a laptop, you may have to pull the battery first. Then I did it a second time. After the second time, Windows booted in recovery mode. From there, I was able to do a system restore. Now my mouse and keyboard are working again. However, I'm afraid of what Windows 10 is going to do next... I have already had a number of issues with Windows 10 malfunctioning and am very frustrated by its fragility. I'm crossing my fingers.

Since you mentioned that the keyboard works in the BIOS, it shouldn't be a hardware fault with either the keyboard or the USB port

EDIT: If you have another keyboard and/or mouse, i'd try using that too.